# How do you find the package a Delphi unit (not a component) comes from?

Tags: delphi, package

I've read following question: [How do you find the package a Delphi component comes from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263138/how-do-you-find-the-package-a-delphi-component-comes-from) It provides means to find out in which package a component resides. But I have "advanced" version of this question:

`unit1` of `SomePackage` is in "`uses`" section of `MyUnit`. `MyUnit` belongs to `MyPackage` which makes `unit1` to be automatically implicitly imported into `contains` section of `MyPackage`. I would like to avoid this by adding `SomePackage` to `requires` section of `MyPackage`.

How to find out what `SomePackage` is if I have multiple packages and all of them contain no `*.pas` files, but `*.bpl` and `*.dcu` only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PE-Information expert in GExperts experimental(!) has got a tab containing information for packages. It shows all units that the package contains (and also the package description, the required packages and the exported classes)

https://blog.dummzeuch.de/gexperts-documentation/pe-information-expert/

That's not quite what you want, but better than nothing. You could probably take the source code from there and write a tool that searches all packages for a given unit name.